# LocalDate comparison, getting orders between two dates

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, localdate

```
    public List<WorkItem> getWorkItemsByDate(String startDate, String endDate) throws ParseException {
    LocalDate parsedStartDate = LocalDate.parse(startDate);
    LocalDate parsedEndDate = LocalDate.parse(endDate);
    return workItemRepository.findAll().stream().filter(w -> w.getUpdateDate().isAfter(parsedStartDate) &&
                                                w.getUpdateDate().isBefore(parsedEndDate))
                                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

I have two dates that I want to compare between and find all the workitems(has LocalDate) for the dates. 
I have one problem though I can't figure out how to check for the same date. 
When you run a date in my code it works fine untill you write the date that the item was created, then it does not work.

How do I make this work with say 2018-05-28 - 2018-05-28, if the items were created on this day it will not work in my lambda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the day is the same day it is not before, nor after, so it will return false in these cases.

You can replace the `isAfter` and `isBefore` with a call to `compareTo` and check the `int` return value. Less clear in code, but still understandable.

```
.filter(w -> w.getUpdateDate().compareTo(parsedStartDate) >= 0 && w.getUpdateDate().compareTo(parsedEndDate) <= 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

I usually use “not before” as a short way to say “on or after”. And the other way around:

```
    w -> ! w.getUpdateDate().isBefore(parsedStartDate)
            && ! w.getUpdateDate().isAfter(parsedEndDate)
```

Depending on taste you may of course use the more wordy but also more direct

```
    w -> (w.getUpdateDate().isEqual(parsedStartDate) || w.getUpdateDate().isAfter(parsedStartDate))
            && (w.getUpdateDate().isBefore(parsedEndDate) || w.getUpdateDate().isEqual(parsedEndDate))
```