# Java, regular expression for time

Tags: java, regex, datetime, textfield, dateformatter

I have a textfield in Java eclipse interface for which i want to validate it to accept only time format, but I don't want seconds included.

How do I validate it to accept only this format **hh:mm** but from hours 8:00 morning till 16:00 afternoon.

P.s TextField variable name is txtOra.

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow. I recommend you to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for information on asking a good and well-received question. You are missing a couple points there.

Comment: Which graphic framework are you using? Is it swing, awt, or maybe android? Are you sure it is `TextField` or maybe it is `JTextField` (these are not the same and solution may depend on it).

Comment: Possibly related: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/swing/1.4/ftf.html

Comment: [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25873636/regex-pattern-for-exactly-hhmmss-time-string) Pattern: ```([8-9]|1[0-6]):([0-5][0-9])```

Comment: This question has been asked and answered with variations many times. For example [Regex pattern for EXACTLY HH:MM:SS time String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25873636/regex-pattern-for-exactly-hhmmss-time-string).

Answer (score 4):

Just parse it with a `DateTimeFormatter`

```
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("H:mm");

LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.parse("16:16", dateTimeFormatter);
```

if `parse` does not throw an exception you have a valid time.

Then check for your constraints with `LocalDate#isAfter` and `LocalDate#isBefore`

Look it up here to find more patterns https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

Comment: I would also validate that the time is within the given range after parsing.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) you can use [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) where you can use [`isBefore`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#isBefore-java.time.LocalTime-) and [`isAfter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#isAfter-java.time.LocalTime-) like so :

```
public static boolean checkDateIsCorrect(String input){
    //Format your date
    LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(input, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("H:mm"));
    //Then check if the time is between 8:00 and 16:00
    return !time.isBefore(LocalTime.parse("08:00")) 
                || !time.isBefore(LocalTime.parse("16:00"));
}
```

Comment: `H` alone can accept 8 as well as 08 (so you don’t need optional parts). Your method rejects times lying on the limits 08:00 and 16:00, which I suspect wasn’t intended from the asker.

Comment: @OleV.V. I don't understand *Your method rejects times lying on the limits 08:00 and 16:00, which I suspect wasn’t intended from the asker.*

Comment: What is the expected result of `checkDateIsCorrect("8:00")`? What is the actual result? Same question for `"16:00"`.

Comment: @OleV.V. I got it, what about now?

Comment: If you want that way of solving it, I think you need 16:01.

Comment: Similar to [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50564365/5772882)

Comment: Yes, your way not need to use `7:59` and `16:01` I like it I will go with that one instead thank you @OleV.V.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following function to validate a time string with HH:MM (24 Hours Format)

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public boolean validate(final String time){
      String TIME24HOURS_PATTERN = 
                "([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]";
      Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(TIME24HOURS_PATTERN);
      Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(time);
      return matcher.matches();

}
```

Comment: how would you extend this to include seconds? "([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]" ?

Comment: @ennth, solution given by you should work for including seconds